# Start Python web server and return control to app

Tags: python, flask

Can I start a web server like Flask or Bottle (perhaps in a new thread?) and then return control to the application? The default examples for both these frameworks steal control and do not return when I start the server.

Comment: If you put it in a thread it should return control.

Answer (score 2):

You can start in a new thread. You should set the daemon flag so that Ctrl+C can end the script.

```
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    app.run(
      port=7777,
      host='localhost'
    )

if '__main__'==__name__:
  logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

  thread = ServerThread()
  thread.daemon = True
  thread.start()
```